# What does "understand deal" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am totally confused by this sentence. Can anybody help me with the phrases used in it? (understand deal, the second "for")?

"So he recently took to Twitter to publicly invite Silicon Valley investors to spend a "few weeks homeless, functionally impaired or caring for a child with complex needs." On a phone call with CNBC, he said an experience like this is "bread and butter" for design thinking and customer development. **"How else will a VC understand deal flow for a population for served by Medicaid?"**"

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/09/medicaid-chief-andrey-ostrovsky-silicon-valley-missing-unicorns.html

Comment: You are parsing it incorrectly. "How else will (a VC) (understand) (deal flow) (for a population served by Medicaid)?" I presume VC is venture capitalist. The "for" before "served" should not be there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a typo.